# Reactjs is not rendering my state properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[This](https://github.com/bertolo1988/todo-app) is my todo app made with ReactJS. **I am not able to delete todo's properly.**

**It always removes the last todo, regardless of the one i click.**

Example: If i click to delete 'Buy socks', it will remove 'Oi them'. If i try to check my list state in the debugger, it deleted the correct ToDo.

I uploaded the code to [GitHub repository](https://github.com/bertolo1988/todo-app), it was setup with create-react-app should be very easy to setup.

From what i understand the todo entry that i delete in the state of the TodoList does not remove the state of the removed children, and therefore it does not cease to exist.

**How do i take care of it? What am i doing wrong?**

**Hint**: [here](https://gist.github.com/bertolo1988/2d78da15db8c54eeba11eb29c0653d43) is a gist with unnecessary code removed.

Comment: you shouldnt bind the state to the click event, instead bind the todo object or the index of the object

Comment: it's better to add `delete` event on a simple `todo`, and pass a callback from `todolist` to `todo`

Comment: But that will not solve my problem.

Comment: I am currently working on creating a solution that is a little more organized and easy to follow. The application should really only contain a single state that lives in the parent and the children inherit that state and pass data back to the parent to update the state. Will update when complete

Comment: Yes i agree. But why cant i just pass state to the child and edit there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now your `deleteTodo` function has the wrong `this` bound to it. The `deleteTodo` function wants to set the state of the parent component, and calls `this.setState()`. However, the `this` is bound in the child's constructor. You want to bind `this` to the `deleteTodo` in the constuctor of the parent component: `TodoList`.

That way when the function is called, it will correctly set the state of `TodoList` with the new, filtered list of todos.

So be more specific about the changes needed in the code you posted.

First in the constructor of TodoList, bind deleteTodo

```
this.deleteTodo = this.deleteTodo.bind(this)
```

Now when `this.setState` is called in the deleteTodo function it will be setting the state of the correct component.

Now we need to make sure we correctly pass in the argument of delete todo.
In the Todo component, replace

```
onClick={this.props.deleteTodo.bind(this,todoText)}
```

with

```
function(){this.props.deleteTodo(todoText)}
```

You do not need to bind here, wrap the deleteTodo function so that when onClick is called the wrapper function calls deleteTodo with the correct argument.

When the element is clicked, the function assigned to the onClick prop will be called, with a click event object as an argument. We set this function up to call deleteTodo with the correct argument, ignoring the event object.

Comment: How can i accomplish this?

Comment: @TiagoBértolo The mechanisms of method binding for React are all over the place, just search for it

Comment: can you link me a good resource please? I am only being able to find stuff with plugins or too old.

Answer (score -3):

```js
    class Todo extends React.Component {
        /*...*/
        handleDelete() {
          this.props.deleteTodo(this.state.text);
        }
        /*...*/
        render() {
            let priorityClass = this.switchPriority(this.state.priority);
            let completedClass = this.getCompletedClass(this.state.completed);
            let todoClasses = classNames(priorityClass, completedClass);
            return (
                <tr className={todoClasses}>
                <td><button ref='deleteTodo' onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this)} className='close-button'>&times;</button></td>
                <td  onClick={this.handleClick} className='todo-row'>{this.state.text}</td>
                </tr>);
        }
    }
    
    class TodoList extends React.Component {
        /*...*/
        deleteTodo(todoToRemove) {
            let newTodos = this.state.todos.filter((_todo) => _todo.text !== todoToRemove);
            this.setState({
                todos: newTodos
            });
        }
      /*...*/
    }
```

Could you try this ? I think it is because you are binding deleteTodo two times.

Comment: Can you retry, I have made some changes. I think it is because you are binding deleteTodo two times.

Comment: Code dumps without explanations aren't super-effective. Please limit code to the minimum necessary to explain, and discuss the "why" not just the "what". Thanks!

Comment: Posting a code snippet instead of explaining the problem and the solution does not make for a good answer.